# D d/m/y Convert to another format PHP

Tags: php, date

I have date stamps from external source as per below format

```
Tue 6/02/2018
```

However when trying to convert the date to Y-m-d for SQL format the date get skewed, using the below;

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('Tue 6/02/2018');
//ends up being Y-d-m
```

I have set the timezone earlier using

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Brisbane');
```

Comment: I get 2018-06-05 00:00:00

Comment: But if I use Fri 2/02/2018 i get the correct date back ...

Comment: Because `strtotime()` confuse with day and month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtotime()` [cannot parse](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) the format `"Tue 6/02/2018"` correctly. You have to use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to parse from your format.

```
$time = 'Tue 6/02/2018';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("D j/m/Y", $time) ;
echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s") ; // 2018-02-06 07:12:19
```

You also could use `new DateTimeZone()` as:

```
$time = 'Tue 6/02/2018';
$tz = new DateTimeZone('Australia/Brisbane');
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("D j/m/Y", $time, $tz) ;
echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s") ; // 2018-02-06 17:17:48
```